# php regex remove few string from url

Tags: javascript, php

Below is my code in javascript that remove special character using regex.

```
var yourInput = "string here";
re = /[`~!@$%^&*()+\=;'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi;
var isSplChar = re.test(yourInput);
if(isSplChar)
{
    var no_spl_char = yourInput.replace(/[`~!@$%^&*()+\;'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '');
    $(this).val(no_spl_char);
}
```

i want similiar version for php i tried below code but i gives error

```
$input_lines="string here";
preg_replace("/[`~!@$%^&*()+\;'",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/", "", $input_lines);
```

what am i missing

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `"` char and to change your delimiters :

```
preg_replace("~[`\~!@$%^&*()+\;'\",.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]~", "", $input_lines);
```

Comment: i get Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier ']'

Comment: then you should change your delimiters, escaping `/` does not seem to be enough to PHP, I'm not sure why... just edited my answer with a working code :)